# Android java syntax help

Tags: java, android

```
import com.ave.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;



public class Menu extends Activity{
ImageButton select;    
int isClicked = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        select = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.select);
select.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
             if (isClicked == 0){
                select.setImageResource(R.drawable.select_pressed);
                isClicked = 1;
             }
             else{
                select.setImageResource(R.drawable.select);
                isClicked = 0;
             }
        }});
}

ImageButton audio;    
int isClicked1 = 0;{

audio = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.audio);
audio.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
             if (isClicked1 == 0){
                audio.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio_pressed);
                isClicked1 = 1;
             }
             else{
                audio.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio);
                isClicked1 = 0;
             }
         }
   });
 }
}
```

I'm not sure whats going wrong. There are no errors within the xml files or java class, however, when i go to test out the app via my phone or the AVD, after the splash screen it just randomly force closes.

### LogCat

```
E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-05 10:47:59.318  9362  9362 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.ave/com.ave.Menu}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-05 10:47:59.318  9362  9362 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1618)
07-05 10:47:59.318  9362  9362 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1716)
07-05 10:47:59.318  9362  9362 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:124)
07-05 10:47:59.318  9362  9362 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:968)
07-05 10:47:59.318  9362  9362 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-05 10:47:59.318  9362  9362 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-05 10:47:59.318  9362  9362 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
07-05 10:47:59.318  9362  9362 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method
07-05 10:47:59.318  9362  9362 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-05 10:47:59.318  9362  9362 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-05 10:47:59.318  9362  9362 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-05 10:47:59.318  9362  9362 E AndroidRuntime:    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-05 10:47:59.318  9362  9362 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-05 10:47:59.318  9362  9362 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1693)
07-05 10:47:59.318  9362  9362 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.ave.Menu.<init>(Menu.java:41)
07-05 10:47:59.318  9362  9362 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-05 10:47:59.318  9362  9362 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
07-05 10:47:59.318  9362  9362 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
07-05 10:47:59.318  9362  9362 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1610)
07-05 10:47:59.318  9362  9362 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 11 more
```

Comment: and also, you should learn how to use `adb logcat` prior to post question here.

Comment: @ACM64 ok i figured out how to dump the output to a txtfile, but its not as organized as the console's output. I'm not sure which i should paste to this post.

Comment: @Cataroux, if you are using eclipse then you can open logcat window and view all the logs related to android emulator and your android application.

Comment: @Cataroux, It seems like emulator is not able to find some view (ImageBUtton). Make sure you have mentioned that ImageButton in xml file of your activity.

Comment: @ Shekhar oh its there. I can see it when i switch to the graphical layout view of the main xml. There aren't any errors either.

Comment: @Lukas Knuth the logcat output is up.

Comment: @Cataroux, Have you solved ur problem?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'm not sure if i have to close the post on my own or what?

Comment: you should pick one of the answers as correct and then you and man who answered will get karma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue here is that your onCreate is closed too early. Everything I see should be in the onCreate code block. Remove the } after the first onClick block (marked by }});) and add it back at the end of the file

Comment: you are right. onCreate() is closed too early. but this will generate compile time exception, not runtime exception. I think @Cataroux has posted his code incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried updating the `AndroidManifest.xml` file with your `Activity`s?

Comment: I'm not sure what i would put, because all i've add are imageButton methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have faced this same problem.

Usually this error occurs when particular resource is not found.

In your case, check whether following resource is present in xml file corresponding to your view.

```
select = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.select);
```

OR this resource

```
audio = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.audio);
```

Hope it helps.

Logcat output can help us to pinpoint the problem.